# How can I create a file by using cat in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I create a file by using cat in a bash script?

The commands below work fine through the shell, but not as a script:

```
cat > list.txt
Orange
Apple
Grape
Kiwi
Papaya
Banana
Strawberry
Blueberry
Peach
Pear
CTRL-D
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) within a script:

```
$ cat > list.txt <<EOF
Orange
Apple
Grape
Kiwi
Papaya
Banana
Strawberry
Blueberry
Peach
Pear
EOF
```